# Why there are 7 pins in I/O PORT C of Atmega328P as against 8 pins normally?

Tags: microcontroller, atmega328p

In any 8 bit microcontroller, normally there will be 8 bits per I/O port. But in AVR atmega328P, there are only 7 bits in one of the I/O port (PORT C). What might be the reason for the exclusion of one bit in PORT C?

Comment: *normally there will be 8 pins (bits) per I/O port.* Citidation needed

Comment: Ran out of pins on the package?

Comment: @AlexandervonWernherr: Is asking for a citation not silly? It is his (and my) observation.

Comment: There is no real reason why they have to have that much pins per port. Usually it is just convenient to put it in groups of 8, but if you run out of silicon space to do it (or much more likely, physical space on a package) it seems obvious to disable one of the port's pins.

Comment: @Transistor I have encountered a lot of chips with only 4 pins per port

Comment: @Alex: Of course, but I wouldn't ask you for a citation for that.

Comment: @Transistor "I have encountered" does not require citation; "normally there will be" most certainly does.

Answer (score 6):

There are no more leads on the package.

If you look at the [die of the ATmega328p](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/31/ATMEL_MEGA328P_AU_1328.jpg) (on wikipedia) you will see 32 [wire bonding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire_bonding) points.

But there are less leads on the package, choices have been made, and PC7 has not been wired.